# Where will the Copa Del Rey final 2014 be played?

Tags: football, tournaments

I cannot locate this information anywhere! I'm, of course, referring to [the football (soccer) tournament played in Spain](http://www.rfef.es/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RFEF (Real Federación Española de Fútbol) officially announced that the Copa del Rey final for 2014 will be played in the **Mestalla Stadium, Valencia** (home of Valencia FC).

Source:
http://www.insidespanishfootball.com/97777/copa-del-rey-final-to-be-be-played-at-the-mestalla/

Comment: According to the article, it looks like they *un*officially announced the location.  It will be made official on March 4, assuming the participating teams agree to it and the board officially approves it.

Answer (score 6):

There has been no announcement as to where the final will be played. This will be announced by [RFEF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Spanish_Football_Federation) (Royal Spanish Football Federation, similar to the English FA) once the finalists are known to ensure the ground is neutral.

Odds on the location of the final can be found [here](http://www.nicerodds.co.uk/copa-del-rey-odds).

Answer (score -1):

According to [recent revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=2014_Copa_del_Rey_Final&oldid=595468651) of the Wikipedia article [2014 Copa del Rey Final](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Copa_del_Rey_Final):

> The stadium will be determined on March 4

The reference given there is http://www.marca.com/2014/02/13/futbol/copa_rey/1392248737.html

I do not speak Spanish but using Google Translate I understood that the match will probably be played in Valencia, although the decision will not be official until the next meeting of the Board of the RFEF, scheduled for March 4.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the Wikipedia article [was created after](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=2014_Copa_del_Rey_Final&action=history) this question was posted.

Comment: I have made the answer CW; if someone who speaks Spanish can add more details based on the above links, feel free to do so.